# Building Docker image with `pip3 install pyyaml` returns error: "ImportError: No module named 'importlib.resources'"

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pyyaml

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.6.0-devel-gpu-py3
COPY ./home/ /home/
RUN mkdir /usr/java \
&& cp -r /home/SySeVR/softdir/jdk1.8.0_161 /usr/java \
&& mkdir /usr/ant \
&& cp -r /home/SySeVR/softdir/apache-ant-1.9.14 /usr/ant \
&& rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& cp -r /home/SySeVR/softdir/sources.list /etc/apt/ \
&& rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get update \
&& rm -rf /etc/profile \
&& cp -r /home/SySeVR/softdir/profile /etc \
&& cd /home/SySeVR/softdir \
&& chmod +x env.sh \
&& ./env.sh \
&& apt-get install -y python-setuptools \
&& apt-get install -y python-dev \
&& apt-get install -y python-pip \
&& cd /home/SySeVR/softdir/py2neo-py2neo-2.0 \
&& python2 setup.py install \
&& cd /home/SySeVR/softdir/python-joern-0.3.1 \
&& python2 setup.py install \
&& apt-get install -y graphviz \
&& apt-get install -y libgraphviz-dev \
&& apt-get install -y pkg-config \
&& apt-get install -y python-igraph \
&& apt-get install -y python-virtualenv \
&& pip3 install xlrd \
&& pip3 install gensim==3.4 \
&& pip3 install pyyaml \
&& rm -rf /home/SySeVR/softdir
```

When I try to build an image from that dockerfile, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/core.py", line 14, in
from importlib.resources import path as get_path, read_text
ImportError: No module named 'importlib.resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/certs.py", line 17, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import contents, where
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/certifi/core.py", line 46, in <module>
    Resource = Union[str, "os.PathLike"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 552, in __getitem__
    dict(self.__dict__), parameters, _root=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in __new__
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 512, in <genexpr>
    for t2 in all_params - {t1} if not isinstance(t2, TypeVar)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 190, in __subclasscheck__
    self._eval_type(globalns, localns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py", line 177, in _eval_type
    eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'PathLike'
```

If I remove the second to the last line (`pip3 install pyyaml`), it works fine.

From the error message, it seems it is using python 3.5. I tried to use 3.6 just for pyyaml but no luck. I don't know the proper way to do that.

Comment: `importlib.resources` was new in Python 3.7

Answer (score -1):

This is a package introduced in version 3.7 details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html)

So it needs to be on the docker as part of the packages install, thus add:

pip3 install importlib-resources

Comment: distribution package `importlib-resources` provides import package `importlib_resources`.  the code uses `importlib.resources`, not `importlib_resources`, so this will not work.